# openGL with glew - file missing

Tags: c, ubuntu, opengl, glew

I tried getting [this repository](https://github.com/fmor/demo_ffmpeg_vaapi_gl) to work.

And here is the problem: I saw that the demo program included GLEW as a static library (not sure about that - the source code of GLEW is included. Is that a library then? I don't know) and I thought because I'm on Ubuntu (20.04) that could be done easier. So I used the `sudo apt-get install libglew-dev` to install all needed header files and so on. Easy!  But then there came a part in the demo where the header file `eglew.h` was used and gcc could not find that. I looked into `/usr/include/GL` and this header file was really missing. I tried installing a bunch of other packages. No success.

Does someone out there know how I get the package with this header file? Or is there no other way around than to do it like in the demo with a CmakeList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the missing header file from here which is the official site: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

If not, you can defiantly find the missing header here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/quic-trace/+/refs/heads/master/third_party/glew/include/GL

Comment: So there were other stuff missing, that didn't came with a package. I made a CMakelist and added the files. But still thank you for your reply :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).